# player.js issue with using on ended and on play

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

Everything is working but separate. So my code is:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// when video end open modal
player.on('ended', function() {
   runmovie();
  modal.style.display = "block"; 
});
```

and its works.. but... when i would like to add

```
player.on('play',function(){
document.getElementById('anefra').src = 
'https://player.vimeo.com/video/293755890?autoplay=1';
 setTimeout(function() {
runmovie();
```

}, 6000);});

Then script runs player.on play, and never player on ended... any idea why?!

Comment: perhaps `some code` breaks something - without seeing `some code` it's a mystery wrapped in a riddle inside an enigma

Comment: ye i found a issue

Comment: the thing is about new url

Comment: so, you set the URL of the movie to something different, which prevents `ended` event from firing? in that case, don't do that

Comment: yes thats the thing...

Comment: so i have to find solution.. beouse i have around 200 movies and i have to put intro before them

Comment: your code does not make it clear what you want to do - you've found what you're doing wrong now, so have you tried fixing your code?